# Ajax Update within the While Loop - JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do an Ajax Update within the While Loop that retrieves info from database. The Update is triggered by an onclick event of a button next to a form input that exists in each row.

Figuring I need to pass 2 variables - the id of the row and the new text from the input. Then when success: I need to update the input with the new value and update column B (static html) as well.

```
HTML

  <table id='movies'>
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>COLUMN A</th>
  <th>COLUMN B</th>
  <th>MOVIE ID</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  while ($row = oci_fetch_array($ajaxmovies, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

  <td> . $row['MOVIENAME'] . </td>
  <td> . $row['MOVIEID'] . </td>
  <td> 

   echo "<input type='text' id='mov' name='movie' maxlength='8' pattern='[0-9]{8}' value='" . $row['MOVIEID'] . "'>";

   echo "<button class='button_save' data-id='" . $row['MOVIEID'] . "'>Save</button>";

  </td>
  </tr>

  }

  </tbody>
  </table>
```

And so here is the Ajax script - that is failing - hopefully looking for solution with explanation. thanks.

```
  <script>

  $('.button_save').click(function() { // onclick handler to each of the buttons

  var val1 = $('#mov').val(); // value from input of each row
  var val2 = $(this).attr("data-id");  // Get the ID of the button that was clicked on

   $.ajax({ // AJAX request
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'mov_update.php',
       data: { text1: val1, text2: val2 },

       success: function(response) {
          // $('#result').html(response);
          $('#mov').val(val1); // updates input new value
    }
  });
});

  </script>
```

and here is the DB update mov_update.php

```
  // DB Connection

  $text1 = $_POST['text1'];
  $id = $_POST['text2'];

  $sql = "UPDATE SCHEMA.MOVIEW SET MOVIE=:mov
                               WHERE ID=:id";

  $objParse = oci_parse($conn, $sql); 

  oci_bind_by_name($objParse, ':id', $id);
  oci_bind_by_name($objParse, ':mov', $text1);

  $objExecute = oci_execute($objParse, OCI_DEFAULT);

  if ($objExecute) {

      oci_commit($conn); 

      echo $text1 . $id;
  }
```

Comment: ids should be unique, you are using the same id for your input text in foreach statement meaning you have multiple input boxes holding the same id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element with `id` **must be unique** on the page. So, creating tens of `<input type='text' id='mov' />` is **not correct**. You should use "dynamic" ids instead, for example:

```
echo "<input type='text' id='mov-" . $row['MOVIEID'] . "' name='movie' maxlength='8' pattern='[0-9]{8}' value='" . $row['MOVIEID'] . "'>";
echo "<button class='button_save' data-id='" . $row['MOVIEID'] . "'>Save</button>";
```

I suppose, your `$row['MOVIEID']` stores **unique** values. And because of that, 
`id='mov-" . $row['MOVIEID'] . "'` are strings like `mov-2`, `mov-3`, `mov-10` etc.

Now in your js you can:

```
var val2 = $(this).attr("data-id");  // Get the ID of the button that was clicked on
var val1 = $('#mov-' + val2).val();  // value from `input` which is connected the clicked button

$.ajax({ // AJAX request
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'mov_update.php',
  data: { text1: val1, text2: val2 },
  success: function(response) {
      // $('#result').html(response);
      //$('#mov').val(val1); // updates input new value
      // not sure what this is for, as field value is already `val1`
      $('#mov-' + val2).val(val1);
   }
});
```

Comment: Personally, I would use `data-` pair attributes rather than semantic IDs, but the principle is the same.

Comment: I have this working now - except how do I update COLUMN B with the new updated movie id after the DB updates? It still displays the old value when I want to display the new updated value from the DB? Assuming this happens in the success function.

Comment: What is column B?

Comment: Column B just displays a static Movie ID from the DB - but it shows the old value after I update it - I need the ajax to refresh that cell

Comment: Echo some data in php script and it will be in response variable in success().